# PowerBI: how to create several measures at once?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to create several PowerBI measures at once?

Not only in two seperate steps like

```
Measure1 = SUM(df[var1])
```

and then a 2nd measure

```
Measure2 = SUM(df[var2])
```

but in one step like

```
Measure1 = SUM(df[var1]),
Measure2 = SUM(df[var2])
```

(this doesnt work)

maybe even bulkwise or with a kind of loop?

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://exceleratorbi.com.au/copy-measures-between-2-power-bi-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at Tabular Editor's advance scripting functionality.
you can create a script in c# to automate the creation of measures
https://docs.tabulareditor.com/Useful-script-snippets.html
eg.

```
var meas1 = c.Table.AddMeasure("Measure1, "SUM(df[var1]),"") 
meas1.FormatString = "0.00";
meas1.Description = "This measure is the sum of column var1 "; 

var meas2 = c.Table.AddMeasure("Measure2, "SUM(df[var2]),"") 
meas2.FormatString = "0.00";
meas2.Description = "This measure is the sum of column var2" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ugly way to do it.

1. Save your pbix file using the option `Save as` and choose `pbit` extension (pivot file). Say the full name will be `test.pbit`.
2. In Explorer change the extension of the file from `test.pbit` to `test.zip`.
3. Extract from `test.zip` the zipped data to a new folder.
4. Go inside the folder and find the file `DataModelSchema`.
5. Open `DataModelSchema` with Notepad++ or any other favourite text editor.
6. Ctr+F and search for your measure. It will take you some time to get used to the structure of this file, but hopefully, you can grasp it. You may copy and paste measure how you like.
7. When you are done, save the file.
8. Copy the saved `DataModelSchema` file and go to your test.zip file. Open it entering inside. Paste there the `DataModelSchema`.
9. Follow the reverse path. Change extension back to pbit. Open file in Power BI. That's it.